# Deploy Jekyll "_site" from GitHub with Capistrano

Tags: capistrano, jekyll

I'm trying to deploy just my Jekyll-generated "_site" folder to a "release" with Capistrano. I've confirmed that Capistrano works but it's currently deploying everything on my GitHub-hosted repo.  Is what I want possible?

My `deploy.rb` file currently looks like this...

```
set :application, "kaidez.com"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:kaidez/kaidez.com.git"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :scm, "git"
set :user, "myUsername"
set :scm_passphrase, "myPassword"
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, "/my/remote/branch/"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

role :web, "kaidez.com"
role :app, "kaidez.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Jekyll need to compile the website, you either need to:

1. compile the site locally and add the files to version control
2. compile the site locally prior to uploading
3. compile the site on the server after uploading
4. use something like [`rack-jekyll`](https://github.com/adaoraul/rack-jekyll) to compile your site when requested

After trying to do something similar to you, I ended up scraping Capistrano in favor of writing my own, simple rake task which compiled the site and used rsync to upload the changes.